# graphQl - Argument has invalid value Expected \"contentfulStranNaslovQueryString_2\", found not an object

Tags: javascript, graphql

I am trying to query some data from a contentful API using gatsby's built-in graphiQL.

EDIT: after a suggestion from the comments, I made a introspection query to get the schema information:

```
{
 "name": "contentfulStranNaslovQueryString_2",
  "kind": "INPUT_OBJECT"
}
```

When I run this query:

```
{
  contentfulStran {
    id
    naslov
  }
}
```

I get the expected result (the first entry for the data model):

```
{
  "data": {
    "contentfulStran": {
      "id": "c2tD44y2tDe8QC4yqkwMOgo",
      "naslov": "Novice"
    }
  }
}
```

But now I would like to pass in a query parameter that only gets data specified on the naslov field. I tried this:

```
{
  contentfulStran(naslov: "Ponudba") {
    id
    naslov
  }
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Argument \"naslov\" has invalid value \"Ponudba\".\nExpected \"contentfulStranNaslovQueryString_2\", found not an object.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 27
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any chance you could show us the schema you are trying to query against? The error suggests that the query parameter you have to pass in is not supposed to be a simple scalar string type.

Comment: @Aleon the problem is that the schema is hosted on the contentful webpage, and not really publicly available. All I can see is a JSON preview...I can paste that if you think it would be helpful? But I am starting to feel that this is a problem with the CMS API rather than my query

Comment: If you have access to the API to query things, you can also do an [introspection query](http://graphql.org/learn/introspection/). The interesting part would be figuring out what the type `naslov` is. If it's not as simple string, there should be a defined input type somewhere that tells you exactly how to construct it.

Comment: Querying for something like this could be a start:
    {
      __type(name: "contentfulStranNaslovQueryString_2") {
        name
        fields {
          name
          type {
            name
            kind
          }
        }
      }
    }

Comment: I've edited the question - the query string seems to be of type `"INPUT_OBJECT"`, which seems very strange to me, since the actual query returns a string?

Comment: We seem to be moving in the right direction. You might need to re-evaluate the way you look at the query. First of all it does not return a string, it returns two strings `id` and `naslov`, and could possibly return more if the schema allows it. Your input parameters are also not strictly dependent on the output, but rather the way the query is defined in the schema itself. Your specific query seems to expect some sort of object, e.g. `{field1: "value", field2: ...}` to identify the items you search for. GraphQL query params are not identical to SQL where clauses.

Comment: Also, to address your earlier comment: Seeing a JSON preview of the schema would most definitely help in providing an answer, if that's what you meant. Same for running the introspection a bit deeper, with the field `fields { name type }`, like I posted above, will tell you exactly what you can pass in as input.

Comment: I am pretty sure the problem is with either `gatsby-source-contentful` or contentful itself. But I think the transform plugin is doing some weird stuff. Since the question really has nothing to do with the query sintax, I'll just delete it. Thank you for your help

Comment: In case you are still interested - this was the correct query `{
  contentfulStran(naslov: {eq: "Ponudba"}) {
    id
    naslov
    zaporedje
    tekst {
      tekst
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Miha answered his own question in the comments. The correct way to filter is:

```
{ 
   contentfulStran(naslov: {eq: "Ponudba"}) 
   { 
      id 
      naslov
      zaporedje
      tekst
      {
        tekst 
      } 
   }
}
```

Note the `{eq: "param"}` object instead of just giving the param.